# Ignore parenthesis contained in a macro parameter

Tags: macros, delimiters

I want that the macro ignore the parenthesis which are parts of the parameter and only conside the last parenthesis as the delimiter, I found a solution with `\text{}`.

Are there any better (and simple) solutions ?

```
\documentclass{report}
\makeatletter
\def\test(#1,#2){ #1--#2}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\test(paremeter (1), paremeter (2))
\test(paremeter (1\text{)}, paremeter (2\text{)})
\end{document}
```

Comment: Will there be just \test((1),(2))` or also annoying text before (1) etc.?

Comment: it can be a string text containing a ")" inside which isnt the end of it (the string), no it can be more than 2 parameters some others may not contain any ")" if that what you asked.

Comment: Why not just use a different delimiter?

Comment: because i found tha a macro definition with a parenthesis delimiters is easy to use musch easier than a curly brace delimiter macro(,,,) macro{}{}{}

Comment: As a compromise, would you be open to the syntax `\test{parameter(1), parameter(2), ..., parameter(n)}`?

Comment: suppose i do, even that i prefere the parenthesis one, we just avoid the issue suppose we encounter the case "}" is within a parameter how to proceed, use another delimiter ?

Comment: There shouldn't be too much problem with braces in the parameters as long as they are matched (that is, left brace data right brace).  Of course a printing brace `\{` and `\}` are OK even if unmatched, but the grouping braces `{` and `}` must be matched.

Comment: actually i prefer to keep the parenthesis syntaxe and include the parameter string that contains a ")" in `\text{}` every time it doesnt bother me, i am just looking if there is a better solution as simple as mine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`xparse` has built in system to match correcty paired delimiters.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand\test{>{\SplitArgument{1}{,}}r()}{\testaux#1}
\NewDocumentCommand\testaux{mm}{ #1--#2}

\begin{document}

\test(paremeter (1), paremeter (2))

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

This works for easy setups, but not for all occasions

```
\documentclass{report}
\makeatletter

\def\@testhelper#1(#2){#2}
\def\test(#1,#2){\@testhelper#1--\@testhelper#2}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\test(Foo (1), Parameter long long long useless stuff before the number appears(2))
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you make it to work only for a single parameter please ? i tried `\def\@testhelper#1{#1}` but it doesnt works, in fact it give the same result as without `\text`

Comment: @guest00: I rather delete this since you did not find it useful at all

Comment: @Christian_Hupfer: yes i couldnt find a general way to include it in my main document, thanks for answering anyway.

Comment: @guest00: Understood -- it could have been improved if I had seen the real application in your `main` document, but alas, there was no further information

Answer (score 0):

Based on the OP's comment that he would consider a macro with a single brace-delimited, comma-separated list.  EDITED to allow the inter-parameter seperator to be specified with `\setdelimiter[]` (default comma).

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{argcounter}
\def\test{}
\newcommand\setdelimiter[1][,]{%
\renewcommand{\test}[1]{%
  \setcounter{argcounter}{0}%
  \parseargs##1#1\relax\relax%
}
\def\parseargs##1#1##2\relax{%
  \stepcounter{argcounter}%
  \expandafter\gdef\csname arg\romannumeral\value{argcounter}\endcsname{##1}%
  \if\relax##2\relax\gdef\narg{\theargcounter}\else\parseargs##2\relax\fi%
}
}
\setdelimiter
\begin{document}
\setdelimiter[:]
\noindent\test {A:B}%
There are \narg{} arguments, \argi{} and \argii

\noindent\test {parameter (1): parameter\{2\}: parameter {3}:E}%
There are \narg{} arguments: \argi{}, \argii, \argiii, and \argiv\par  

\setdelimiter[,]
\noindent\test {A:B}%
There is \narg{} arguments, \argi{}

\noindent\test {A,B}%
There are \narg{} arguments, \argi{} and \argii
\end{document}
```

[image]